# responsive horizontal menu with dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a **horizontal responsive menu** that works great, here is [link to the page with it](http://isellrye.com/)

I tried to make a new one with dropdown menus but can't get it to work. Instead  of having a dropdown appear on *hover*, it shows the menus automatically in the line below. Here is link to codepen showing the errors [http://codepen.io/mlegg10/pen/akLaVA](http://codepen.io/mlegg10/pen/ZWdqZE)

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $('nav').prepend('<div id="responsive-nav" style="display:none">Menu</div>');
  $('#responsive-nav').on('click', function() {
    $('nav ul').slideToggle()
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {

    if ($(window).innerWidth() < 768) {
      $('nav ul li').css('display', 'block');
      $('nav ul').hide()
      $('#responsive-nav').show()
    } else {
      $('nav ul li').css('display', 'inline-block');
      $('nav ul').show()
      $('#responsive-nav').hide()
    }

  });

  $(window).resize();

});

$(document).on('scroll', function() {

  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('#nav').addClass('fixed')
  } else {
    $('#nav').removeClass('fixed')
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Georgia;
}
#menu-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  background-color: #ff4500;
  text-align: center;
}
#header h1 {
  padding: 15px 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#nav {
  background-color: #036;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#nav.fixed {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
nav ul li a {
  padding: 0 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
#responsive-nav {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
#content {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
}
#drop-nav li ul li {
  border-top: 0px;
  #drop-nav li ul li {
    border-top: 0px;
  }
  ul li a {
    display: block;
    background: #036;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #fff;
  }
  ul li a:hover {
    background: #f00;
  }
```

```html
**this part is in the head tags:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://responsive-nav.com/demo/responsive-nav.js"></script>**

<header id="menu-bar">
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Accomodations</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Amenities</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Rates</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Links</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Dropwdown 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code has lots of unclosed line endings - you are missing the semicolons quiet often.

Additionally, jQuery will apply `nav ul` to all elements it finds. Meaning if there is a second occurrence, which is the case in your case, it will be applied to that too.

Instead: you should give your level 0 menu a clean, identifiable class, which you can preciesly target:

```
<!-- Your new HTML Markup -->
<nav class="mother-of-all-dropdown-lists">
```

and then in your jQuery:

```
$('.mother-of-all-dropdown-lists').slideToggle();
```

Sorry, that I keep writing, there are jQuery selectors wrong as well:

The id / hashtag is missing, so..:

```
$('nav ul li').css('display','inline-block');
$('nav ul').show()
```

should be:

```
$('#nav ul li').css('display','inline-block');
$('#nav ul').show();
```

Comment: I tried that http://codepen.io/mlegg10/pen/ZWdqNY and either I didn't do that right or it didn't work :(

Comment: Did you change the rest of your jQuery and CSS selectors according to this? Sure, you need to apply the whole new naming to the rest of your document, otherwise it will only be applied to some things, not everything.

Comment: Ok, it's not in your fiddle. It seems that you did not understand the concept of a dropdown, sorry to be honest. You should really first understand how a dropdown works. I have answered that question a couple of days ago, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155396/css-dropdown-menu-closes-before-i-click/38155581#38155581

Comment: I thought that I did. Don't you see the changes in the new codepen.io/mlegg10/pen/ZWdqNY ?

Comment: Yes, you have changed one selector, but the rest is still the same:
$('nav ul').slideToggle() is already wrong. As I said man, please do a real drilldown of the concept of a dropdown first. Then the code you have in front of you will make sense to you. My explaination to this concept is 2 comments above.

Comment: I can't figure it out. I have MS and my brain is in overload over this. :(

Comment: The code that you are using is a bit blown up, it would take pretty long to through it with you step by step. The very very best website to learn stuff like this is http://www.developphp.com This guy goes through lot of stuff, very basic and very well explained. Look in the CSS section, if you don't get it at all, drop me a mail at tobiashopp.info. My ex-girlfriend has MS too, so I feel with you man. Wish you all the best.

Comment: http://codepen.io/mlegg10/pen/jAGZVd is the current pen. I added the info for the javascripts and images for the hamburg menu when it's small. I only want dropdowns for the Links menu. I research more on how to add them. I've been doing websites for 18 yrs and this one really has me, I must be at a mental block. :P